# Benefits of EBS IO1 over GP3 volume type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Why should one uses IO1 volume over GP3 when it is now possible to manually enter the number of IOPS desired for the GP3 volume ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It always depends on what your workload needs. The documentation has a nice comparison chart: [EBS Volume Types: Solid state drives (SSD)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html)

The main differences are the following:

- gp3 can scale up to 16.000 IOPS whereas io1 can scale up to 64.000 IOPS
- io1 volumes support EBS Multi-Attach and gp3 doesn't

If you need EBS Multi-Attach or more than 16k IOPS, you'll probably want to go with io1 volumes, otherwise gp3 will usually be fine.

Comment: Clear answer. Will definitely help me out in my choice. Thanks